# how to make my app supportting zh_CN?

Tags: ipad

I want my app to support zh_CN.
my code is "⋯⋯setlocale(LC_ALL, "zh_CN");⋯⋯"。
problem comes with, it works in simulator, but not in my iPad.

wht's wrong!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't use setlocale() on iOS to perform localisation (it exists on Mac OS X, which is why it works in the simulator - but Cocoa apps don't use it either). Here's [Apple's overview of i18n and l10n in iOS applications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/InternatAndLocaliz.html) - simply put you provide a set of resources in zh_CN.lproj, and if your user chooses that locale she gets those resources instead of the English (or whatever other language(s) you support).